# Design a parameter $k$ for a second order ODE $\ddot{x}(t) = f(t,k)$ subjected to a set of initial and terminal constraints.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-system

I have a nonlinear differential equation as follows

\begin{align}
\ddot{x}(t) = f(\theta(t),k),
\end{align}

where $f$ is a function of the time variable $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is the designed parameter, and $\theta(t)$ is a known function of time. The function $\theta(t)$ only depends on time and it is a quite complicated so I cannot integrate to find $x(t)$ and $\dot{x}(t)$ analytically.

**My task is:** compute the parameter $k$ such that following initial/terminal conditions should be met as good as possible:

\begin{align}
x(0) = 0, \quad \dot{x}(0) = 0, \quad x(t_{f}) = \bar{x},
\end{align}

where the terminal time $t_{f}$ and the value of $\bar{x}$ are both known.

**My question is**: is there any elegant way to solve such problem?

**My current idea:** I will formulate an optimization problem as below:

\begin{align}
&\min \quad J = x^{2}(0) + \dot{x}^{2}(0) + [x(t_{f}) - \bar{x}]^2 \\
& \quad {k}
\end{align}

Then I will use a nonlinear programmer to solve. But I think it is a bit brute to solve in that way.

I appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: This ode is linear but non-homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon! I figured out that it is not possible to obtain an analytical solution for $x(t)$ and $\dot{x}(t)$, and formulating an optimization problem for this task is not a good idea as well. However, I can separate the parameter $k$ such that $\ddot{x}(t) = L(\theta(t)) + kR(\theta(t))$, then using numerical integration to impose the given initial and terminal conditions.

Comment: as you have written the equation, the solution is $x(t)=x(0)+{\dot x}(o)t+\int_0^tdt'\int_0^{t'}dt''f(\theta(t''),k)$. This has a closed form or not depending the known functions $f$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In my case, $f(\theta(t),k)$ is a nested trigonometric function (e.g. $\tan(\sin(t))$) so as far as I know, it has no closed form of antiderivative. Therefore, I am only able to use numerical integration.

Comment: Then, in such a situation, the inescapable approach is the numerical one.

Comment: It is clear now. Thanks @Jon!